# Vapour pressure of a liquid

Tags: physical-chemistry

Today I studied that vapour pressure of a liquid is constant at a given temperature. I want to ask that "how do we determine the vapour pressure at a given temperature? " Also since evaporation causes cooling so" do we have to supply heat to the system to keep its temperature constant while determining vapour pressure?" Please help....

Comment: You measure the pressure of the vapor over an isothermal closed container of the liquid.

Comment: Experimental procedure here http://www.csun.edu/~ml727939/coursework/695/vapor%20pressure/Vapor%20Pressure.htm

Comment: Simply use the Clausius-Clapeyron equation - 
$$
\ln \Bigg(\dfrac{P_1}{P_2}\Bigg) = \dfrac{\Delta H_{vap}}{R}\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{T_1} - \dfrac{1}{T_2}\Bigg)
$$

Comment: @Farcher, in my opinion, your comment should probably be expanded a bit and submitted as an answer.  Also, that's a nice, easily understood reference.

Comment: @JonCuster  i just wanted to know that when a liquid evaporates then its temperature goes down .It no longer remains at the initial temperature.so the obtained vapour pressure will not be that at the initial temperature  If we want to find the vapour pressure at initial temperature then what ýshould we do,

Comment: In equilibrium, the vapor and the liquid are at the same temperature. So, yes, you need to control/maintain the temperature of the liquid+vapor to accurately measure the vapor pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The saturated vapour pressure of a liquid at a given temperature is the vapour pressure above the liquid surface when the vapour and liquid are in dynamic equilibrium with one another at that temperature.

What that means is that the rate at which liquid molecules become vapour is exactly the same as the rate at which vapour molecules become liquid.

If the temperature is lowered the initial rate at which liquid molecules become vapour is smaller than the rate at which vapour molecules become liquid.
This means that there is a net flow of vapour molecules to liquid and hence the vapour pressure decreases.
This continues until the vapour pressure is low enough for the dynamic equilibrium to be established again.
The saturated vapour pressure at that lower temperature has therefore decreased.
Some external system must have abstracted heat from the liquid and vapour to produce the lowering of the temperature which resulted in the lowering of the saturated vapour pressure.

Suppose you had some liquid and vapour in dynamic equilibrium in a container which did not conduct heat and the container expanded.
The expansion would reduce the vapour pressure and there would be a net transfer of liquid molecules into vapour molecules.
However that would also have the effect of lowering the temperature of the liquid and vapour because energy needs to be supplied to convert liquid into vapour and that energy will come from the lowering of the average kinetic energy of the molecules - a lowering of the temperature.
So the equilibrium state would have a lower saturated vapour pressure than before.

An experimental procedure to measure the saturated vapour pressure at different temperatures is [described here](http://www.csun.edu/~ml727939/coursework/695/vapor%20pressure/Vapor%20Pressure.htm).